# integrating bootstrap with isotope

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

In the link below I wanna convert a list of `DIV`s to 3 columns Grid by adding class `span4` of bootstrap (and masonry layout mode).
[Demo - twitter bootstrap & isotope](http://mhesabi.com/test/test.html)

```
$('#grid').on('click', function() {
    $('.item').hide().addClass('span4');
    $('.item:nth-child(3n+1)').css('margin-left', 0); // remove extra margin-lefts
    $('.item').show();
    $('#posts').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        resizable: false,
        animationEngine: 'best-available'
    });
});
$(window).smartresize(function() {
    $('#posts').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

but as you can see, 3rd column break into the next line. I tried reduce bootstrap `span4` width but that doesn't make any differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the latest version of isotope. integration bug is fixed !

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 3):

***Update 2019***

**Bootstrap 4**

Now that Bootstrap 4 uses flexbox you need to use the `fitRows` layout for Masonry/Isotope: https://www.codeply.com/go/zNeDtV9nLE

**Bootstrap 3 (original answer)**

The example link you provided is broken. The approach that I use for Bootstrap and Isotope is to use bootstrap-responsive.css and custom media queries (in your CSS) to resize the isotope cells (Bootstrap .span3 DIV) accordingly as the browser viewport changes.

These are the @media queries that I tweaked:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  .span3 {
    width: 352px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 980px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .span3 {
    width: 300px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .span3 {
    width: 270px;
  }
}
```

**Complete Bootstrap / Isotope example on Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/60295

Comment: The example shows the basic way to integrate Bootstrap and Isotope.
It really helps me though.